# WebView not loading after internet permissions granted?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, webview

I'm trying to use a WebView to display a webpage in my application. At first, I didn't have any permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml and I got the error 'the webpage at could not be loaded because net::ERR_CACHE_MISS'

But now that I have added the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml, the WebView loads as a empty white box.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package= ... >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application ...
</application>

</manifest>
```

And my Java class:

```
public class location_Fragment extends Fragment {

private WebView webView;

View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
    webView = (WebView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    return rootview;
   }
}
```

Comment: where is your webclient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_layout, container, false);
        webView = (WebView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        return rootview;
       }
    }

      private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use The Following Code

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String data =b.getString("link");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        if(data.equals("")||data.equals("null")) {
            Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"No Link Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        {
            webView.loadUrl(data);
        }
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
               // activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                WebViewActivity.this.setTitle("Loading...");
                WebViewActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if(progress == 100)
                    WebViewActivity.this.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          //  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this,R.style.DialogTheme);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (pDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this,R.style.DialogTheme);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    pDialog = null;
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```